# background-position: -209px -2px, I don't understand negative background position

Tags: css

If I have a 1000x3000 px image and I use a negative background position, how does this exactly work?

I thought it worked by moving to the left 209 pixels then moving up 2 pixels and then showing the part that actually is left, but it seems to do the opposite of that.

Comment: Can you share your code here? If we can see how you've built it, that'll help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "opposite of that"?

Comment: Yes, the -209px or positive 209px refers to the image itself not the container position. So starting at 209px positive removes (for lack of a better word) 209 pixels off the left side. Moving the image to the left but a position:absolute left:-209px moves the container to the left

Comment: a designer built something for me and I am trying to modify it. It works fine I just am trying to understand it.

Comment: I don't understand how it could possibly do the opposite of what you said.  -209px should move the background 209px left, not to the right.  Could you post some of the code?

Comment: I was moving the origin and not the image, now I get it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Background position property actually moves the background image itself relative to the element. For the instance if you use  `{background-position: 0 0}` that means you are positioning `(0,0)` which is top left of your image to the top left of your html element.

The `-ve left offset` means you are moving the image towards left and the `-ve top offset` means moving the image upwards..

In above code first `0` refers to `left offset` and second `0` refers to the `top offset`..

```
{background-position: -209px -2px}
```

means you are moving your image 209px towards left and 2px upwards.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should interpret the negative signs as:

background-position: -x, -y; is the same as saying...
background-position: *x* pixels left, *y* pixels up;

Comment: This is incorrect.  background-position: x pixels right, y pixels down.  X-coordinate comes first.

Comment: Also you are not allowed to seperate x and y by using a `,`.